HTML Canvas Arc only drawing outer sliver of circle
I am working on a visualizer to show the area on a graph that is currently being checked for points from a starting points POV, and within a limited FOV. I am trying to show this with canvas arc, however, instead of filling in the arc area, it is filling in the outermost sliver of the arc.
I have tried drawing lines using the rad angle, and those are successful, it is only the arc that does not appear to work correctly. I would expect that it would complete the arc within the two angles, instead of seemingly subtracting the area of the triangle within the arc.
Relevant section:
let startingLocation = {x:0,y:0};
let angle = 18.43494882292201;
let fovAngle = 30;
let r = 100;
//Convert start and end angles to radians
let theta = angle * (Math.PI / 180);
let theta2 = (angle + fovAngle) * (Math.PI / 180);

//Draw start to end arc area
ctx.moveTo(startingLocation.x, startingLocation.y);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
ctx.arc(startingLocation.x, startingLocation.y, r, theta, theta2, false);
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();

Full snippet


const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const width = document.getElementById('canvas').width;
const height = document.getElementById('canvas').height;

//Starting variables
let fovAngle = 30;
let data = [{
  x: 60,
  y: 20
}];
let startingLocation = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};

//Get angle in radians
let angle = Math.atan2(data[0].y - startingLocation.y, data[0].x - startingLocation.x);
//Convert to degrees
angle = (angle * 180) / Math.PI;
if (angle < 0) {
  angle = angle + 360;
}
drawCanvas(angle);

function drawCanvas(angle) {
  //Clear the canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.textAlign = 'start';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'alphabetic';

  //Draw the points
  var counter = 1;
  for (const point of data) {
    //Draw the point on the canvas (with an offset of two so the point is in the center of the square)
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.fillRect(point.x - 2, point.y - 2, 5, 5);

    //Label the point on the canvas (offset to center number, and to have the number above the square instead of on top of it)
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillText(counter, point.x - 2, point.y - 5);
    counter++;
  }

  //Draw Starting Location
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillRect(startingLocation.x - 2, startingLocation.y - 2, 5, 5);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillText("Start", startingLocation.x - 10, startingLocation.y - 5);

  if (angle != null) {

    //let r=Math.max(width,height)*2;
    let r = 100;

    //Convert start and end angles to radians
    let theta = angle * (Math.PI / 180);
    let theta2 = (angle + fovAngle) * (Math.PI / 180);

    //Draw start to end arc area
    ctx.moveTo(startingLocation.x, startingLocation.y);
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.3;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
    ctx.arc(startingLocation.x, startingLocation.y, r, theta, theta2, false);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.closePath();

    //Draw start angle line
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(startingLocation.x, startingLocation.y);
    ctx.lineTo(startingLocation.x + r * Math.cos(theta), startingLocation.y + r * Math.sin(theta));
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();

    //Draw end angle line
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(startingLocation.x, startingLocation.y);
    ctx.lineTo(startingLocation.x + r * Math.cos(theta2), startingLocation.y + r * Math.sin(theta2));
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();

    console.log(theta, theta2);
  }
}
#canvas {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px 20px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>HTML Canvas Arc</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=200 height=200></canvas>
  </body>

</html>



JSFiddle

Please share a [mcve]. Fiddles can be converted to in-question runnable snippets.

and jsfiddle is down right now anyway

That's because you do call beginPath() after you moveTo the start point, which will remove the moveTo subpath from the current path.
In the absence of a subpath, calling arc() will automatically moveTo the start point of the arc.1
Simply call beginPath before you call moveTo:


const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const width = document.getElementById('canvas').width;
const height = document.getElementById('canvas').height;

//Starting variables
let fovAngle = 30;
let data = [{
  x: 60,
  y: 20
}];
let startingLocation = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};

//Get angle in radians
let angle = Math.atan2(data[0].y - startingLocation.y, data[0].x - startingLocation.x);
//Convert to degrees
angle = (angle * 180) / Math.PI;
if (angle < 0) {
  angle = angle + 360;
}
drawCanvas(angle);

function drawCanvas(angle) {
  //Clear the canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.textAlign = 'start';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'alphabetic';

  //Draw the points
  var counter = 1;
  for (const point of data) {
    //Draw the point on the canvas (with an offset of two so the point is in the center of the square)
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.fillRect(point.x - 2, point.y - 2, 5, 5);

    //Label the point on the canvas (offset to center number, and to have the number above the square instead of on top of it)
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillText(counter, point.x - 2, point.y - 5);
    counter++;
  }

  //Draw Starting Location
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillRect(startingLocation.x - 2, startingLocation.y - 2, 5, 5);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillText("Start", startingLocation.x - 10, startingLocation.y - 5);

  if (angle != null) {

    //let r=Math.max(width,height)*2;
    let r = 100;

    //Convert start and end angles to radians
    let theta = angle * (Math.PI / 180);
    let theta2 = (angle + fovAngle) * (Math.PI / 180);

    //Draw start to end arc area
    ctx.beginPath(); // Call beginPath before moveTo
    ctx.moveTo(startingLocation.x, startingLocation.y);
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.3;
    ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
    ctx.arc(startingLocation.x, startingLocation.y, r, theta, theta2, false);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.closePath(); // useless

    //Draw start angle line
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(startingLocation.x, startingLocation.y);
    ctx.lineTo(startingLocation.x + r * Math.cos(theta), startingLocation.y + r * Math.sin(theta));
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath(); // useless

    //Draw end angle line
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(startingLocation.x, startingLocation.y);
    ctx.lineTo(startingLocation.x + r * Math.cos(theta2), startingLocation.y + r * Math.sin(theta2));
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath(); // useless

    console.log(theta, theta2);
  }
}
#canvas {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px 20px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>HTML Canvas Arc</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=200 height=200></canvas>
  </body>

</html>



Also note that all your closePath calls are useless here. This method is basically a lineTo(startX, startY) but is in no way akin to beginPath().
1. Technically it's the inverse: if there is a subpath, a lineTo from the last point to the start point is drawn, but it boils down to the same.

Why include the superfluous calls to ctx.closePath(); ?

@Blindman67 It's always hard to determine in such a case if we should edit more than the bare minimum to make the point that the one thing we changed was what matterred. But I should indeed probably have added a note about closePath since their use shows they probably got confused.
